# The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I run my python code in visual studio code but it has a problem with the teminal.

Here the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1LLS.png)

I trying to run Machine Learning and have a result program

here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

data = pd.read_csv("D:\Dayroi\ML Learn\Test\car-sales-extended.csv")

x = data.drop("Price",axis=1)
y = data["Price"]

f = ["Make","Colour","Doors"]
one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
tran = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot",one_hot,f)],remainder= "passthrough")
taX = tran.fit_transform(x)
neu = False

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                    hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
if(neu != True):
    clf = RandomForestRegressor()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
scoreH = 1
scoreT = 0
while(scoreT < 0.9):
    Xh, Xt, Yh, Yt = train_test_split(taX,y,test_size=0.2)
    clf.fit(Xh,Yh)
    y_prede = clf.predict(Xt)
    scoreH = clf.score(Xh,Yh)
    scoreT = clf.score(Xt,Yt)
    print(scoreT)
    
pickle.dump(clf,open("heart-disease.nn","wb"))

load = pickle.load(open("heart-disease.nn","rb"))
print(load.score(Xt,Yt))
```

Each good answer is highly appreciated

Comment: Could you run your python code in powershell manually and show the output of error messages?

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499- :

> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 2 (0x2) The system cannot find the file
> specified.

Maybe some file can not be found?
According to your screenshot "heart-disease.nn" is not in the same directory as "Learn.py". However you are making a relative import. Try to use an absolute path to make sure the file can be found.

Comment: But Phython can find a file with full path: data = pd.read_csv("D:\Dayroi\ML Learn\Test\car-sales-extended.csv")

Comment: Yes it seems to finds that file. However in your last lines of your example code above you use relative paths for open("heart-disease.nn", "rb")

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether there's something wrong with your PowerShell.

If you don't mind use command Prompt, you can add the following codes to your
User Uettings (**Ctrl+Shift+P** and search for **Open User Settings**) to change the default terminal:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

Comment: it happen to cmd too

Comment: Try to launch vscode as an administrator.

Comment: I did nothing with CMD it also auto escaped